# ASP.NET MVC tags in a javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, variables

**Hi,**

I need to extract a proper URL for a AJAX call and this is what I have added in my js file :

```
var GetLocationByParentPath = '<%= Url.Content("~/Location/GetLocationsByParent") %>';
```

The ASP.NET MVC tag will however not run so now is the question, how do I fill the GetLocationByParentPath with the correct value?

**BestRegards**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem is that you're trying to accomplish something that is not supported, you cannot use C# code inside js files.

However, you can do it in your aspx files (or cshtml) and the js file can communicate with those, so you have 3 options:

1 . Add a parameter to your function in your js file that accepts the url

inside the js:

```
function yourfunction(url)
{
    var GetLocationByParentPath = url;
}
```

inside your aspx:

```
<script>
    yourfunction('<%= Url.Content("~/Location/GetLocationsByParent") %>');
</script>
```

2 . Add a global js variable that contains this url:

inside your aspx:

```
<script>
    var getLocationsUrl = '<%= Url.Content("~/Location/GetLocationsByParent") %>'
    yourfunction();
</script>
```

inside the js (make sure to define getLocationsUrl before your function runs):

```
function yourfunction()
{
    var GetLocationByParentPath = getLocationsUrl ;
}
```

3 . Use the full hard-coded url (bad for refactoring but simple solution:

inside the js (make sure to define getLocationsUrl before your function runs):

```
    var GetLocationByParentPath = '/Location/GetLocationsByParent';
```

Hope this helpes

Comment: I have a $(document).ready(function ()  in the js file and its here the funtion is executed. If I place alternative 2 in my $(document).ready(function () on the aspx page, will this be executed fista always?

Comment: It depends if you included your js files before you placed the $(document).ready or after. anyway, you don't have to use $(document).ready in your aspx just to set a global variable, it's not a thing you want to happen only after the entire page is loaded. just make the assignment before you include you js file.